# Is it possible to define a method that accepts any number of nested lists?

Tags: java

I have no particular use for this in mind, but is it possible to write a method that accepts any number of nested lists in Java?

I got as far as this:

```
private <T extends List<? extends T>> void masterOfLists(final T list) {

}
```

The small issue with this now is that it never ends. I neither want to lose generics, so simply accepting an `Object` and try casting it to a `List` every pass is not an option in my question.

I hoped it would be clear enough, but appereantly it isn't for some, I want the method `masterOfLists` to accept the following examples (and way more):

- `masterOfLists(new ArrayList<Object>())`
- `masterOfLists(new ArrayList<List<Object>>())`
- `masterOfLists(new ArrayList<List<List<Object>>>())`
- `masterOfLists(new ArrayList<List<List<List<Object>>>>())`

Instead of `Object` it may also be a concrete type like `String`.
The used `List` may be any type of list, like `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` or your custom implementation.

Comment: So, you don't know the depth of lists, but you want to restrict it to a maximum depth or what?

Comment: @Smutje I don't want to restrict it to a particular maximum depth, I only want it to be finite.

Comment: What you mean to say is "the innermost list should contain no list"  - but isn't this mandatory, because how should it be possible to code an infinite nested list?

Comment: @Smutje You are correct there. I don't believe it is possible to create an infinitely nested list.

Comment: Hate to tell you, but you gotta lose the generics.  And if you make it accept `ArrayList<Object>` then you already have.

Comment: Must any of the sublist be either a `List<X>` or a `List<List>` ? Said differently can any List contain both a `X` and a `List<X>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pure `List` won't help you here, you need to define a recursive class.

As an additional source of inspiration you can take a look at my code for [Recursive Tic-Tac-Toe](https://github.com/Zomis/UltimateTTT/blob/master/src/net/zomis/tttultimate/TTBase.java)

You could create a class something like this:

```
public class Recursive<T> {
    List<Recursive<T>> sub;
    T value;

    boolean hasSub() {
        return sub != null;
    }
    T getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    void forEach(Consumer<T> t) {
        if (hasSub())
            sub.forEach(t);
        else t.accept(value);
    }
}
```

You can use logic in this class to prevent it from both having a sub-list and an actual value, using constructors and/or setters.

And then if you want to iterate over it and print out all the sub-items recursively, you can use

```
Recursive<T> recursive;
recursive.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Then your method can look like this:

```
private <T> void masterOfLists(final Recursive<T> list) {
```

You won't get anywhere using pure `List`s because the generic type of the list is not available at runtime, and the generics will only create a mess for you here. Using a recursive class is much easier.

Comment: @Kent Your solution had a good start, but missing the generics part, and a clearer example.

Answer (score -2):

The 'cheap' solution is to extend the ArrayList class with your own name, and force the Generics on the subclass. The SubClass is still an ArrayList....:

```
public class NestingList extends ArrayList<NestingList> {

    // all we do is set the Generics...

}
```

Comment: Use composition over inheritance! :)